# Запятая после "понимание"

Tags: пунктуация

Понимание, где верх и низ.
Здесь сложное предложение? Нужна запятая после "понимание"? Или это "понимание чего?" и запятая не нужна?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна: **Понимание, где верх и низ**.

Правда, предложения пока нет, нужно добавить предикативное слово, например: Необходимо понимание (того), где верх и низ.

Такое предложение является сложноподчиненным, местоименная связь, союзное слово где.

Сомнения в правильности постановки запятой связаны с тем, что существуют **устойчивые сочетания**, имеющие значение одного слова, тогда запятая не ставится.

[XXIX. ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ОБОРОТАХ, НЕ ЯВЛЯЮЩИХСЯ ПРИДАТОЧНЫМИ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯМИ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm)

Сравнить: Просторечные слова стали употреблять **где нужно и где не нужно** (т.е. везде). – Поставить, **где нужно**, недостающие знаки препинания (т.е. там, где нужно).